# Uber trips endpoint throwing HTTP 500

Tags: uber-api

We are getting HTTP 500 error with the following message from Uber trips end point. https://api.uber.com/v1/partners/trips?limit=50&from_time=1538438400&offset=0
{
    "code": "internal_server_error",
    "message": "We have experienced a problem."
}

This code has not changed for 4 weeks in our prod env and seeing this error consistantly since yesterday.

Comment: Might have to do with their endpoint, try checking for developer support from Uber.

Comment: I agree with RickS, if there was a problem with your code, you should get an error in the 400s for invalid parameters or something similar. Unless Uber has no idea what they are doing, and are just throwing 500s when they get a bad request.

Answer (score 2):

Uber got back to me on this. They said they had an outage with trips endpoint

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI0Mg.png)